# Powershell - Carriage returns inserted in output when I use '>'

Tags: powershell, carriage-return

How do I stop this command from dumping carriage returns into my output:

get-content inFILE | select-string "string" > outFILE

Text that was non-wrapped or lacking carriage return suddenly has a carriage return at the 80th character per line. Is there a directive I can use to stop it from doing this to my output?

Comment: `get-content inFILE | select-string "string" | set-string outFILE` was effective in eliminating carriage returns from my output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set-content` instead of `>` ( which is same as `out-file`)

Comment: In case anyone is curious... This happens because > is an alias to Out-File, and Out-File, by default, truncates content @ 80 Characters.   You can change this with | Out-File -Width $n, but at that point, you're not using the redirection operator.  Out-String also does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the location of the inserted CR/LF is based on the buffer or window size of the PowerShell window - When I change the values the location of the CR/LF changes so it doesn't seem to be based on the default of 80.
Using the suggested > rather than out-file didn't change the behavior.

Get-ChildItem calllogs -Filter "*-log" -Recurse | Select-string -Pattern "SWIRcnd" > "C:\temp\RecResults3.txt"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16398
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok - Found that using the -width parameter for out-file resolves this. It also confirms my observation regarding the window/buffer size affecting the output.
-Width 
    Specifies the number of characters in each line of output. Any additional characters are truncated, not wrapped. If you omit this parameter, the width is determined by the characteristics of the host. The default
    for the Windows PowerShell console is 80 (characters).

Comment: Try to avoid answering the same question twice. You should rather update previous answer to keep threads clean and not turning them into chat.